# How to differentiate between the Visitor and User of the system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I did two projects on it. Right now, I am developing a simple intranet training development web-based application where I have three different roles: Admin, Contribute and User. The difference between all of them is that a new menu tab will be appeared in case of Admin and Contribute. I developed this by making the menu bar as a User Control and for role I created property for showing the tab particular for each role.

**Code of the User Control (Menu Tab)(.ascx file):**

```
<ul class="menu" runat="server" >
                    <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Services.aspx">Services</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Quiz.aspx">Quiz Engine</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Suggestion.aspx">Safety Suggestions Box</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">PMOD Saftey Management System</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="BeSafe.aspx">Be Safe !</a>
                        <ul>        
                            <li><a href="Newsletter.aspx">Newsletter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Library.aspx">PSSP Library</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Links.aspx">Useful Links</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="UserProfile.aspx">Profile</a></li>

                    <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Faq.aspx">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Help.aspx">Help</a></li>

                    <li id="menuItem1ToHide" runat="server"><a href="Admin.aspx">Admin</a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="menuItem2ToHide" runat="server"><a href="Contribute.aspx">Settings</a>
                        <ul>        
                            <li><a href="KPIReport.aspx">PMOD Safety Training Detailed Matrix</a></li>
                            <li><a href="UpdateKPIReport.aspx">Update Safety Training Matrix</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li id="menuItem3ToHide" runat="server"><a href="Contribute.aspx">Management</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Dashboard.aspx">Department Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="KPIReport.aspx">PMOD Safety Training Detailed Matrix</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

The system is only accessible by my division employees. Now, they asked me to make it accessible to everybody without showing them the real functionality that contains the division data. I am confused how I will develop this, because it seems that my way that I used for the Admin and Contribute role does not work here. Because the visitor will be able to view most of the pages like any employee in my division with User role.

**How to differentiate between both of them?**

**UPDATE:**

I am developing an intranet web-based application, so I am using the Windows Authentication and I already developed the User Management sub-system instead of using ASP.NET Membership.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get familiar with [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and then you'll understand exactly how to differentiate between users with different roles.

Comment: Yeah, membership is definitely the way to go.  In addition, it will allow you to differentiate between logged in and anonymous visitors of your site.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but could you please read my updated question.

Comment: If you rolled your own, then you'll need to add the concept of roles to your security model.  One thing you might think about is using Active Directory groups to do that for you, since you're using Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If its not too late , or for anybody else, check this:

```
http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/navigation/role-based-permissions-asp4.aspx
```